# how to copy array without references in Type script?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to coppy aray, but when i assign value both arrays are changing values.

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.service.searchTickets().subscribe((resp) => {
  this.dataSource.data = resp.entities;
  this.records = [...this.dataSource.data];
  })
```

this function bellow is calling when i  slide toggle and here i assign username.

```
displayValue(value: TicketsList) {
let index;
index = Number(value.key);

this.dataSource.data[value.key!].status = !this.dataSource.data[value.key!].status;
this.dataSource.data[index].supervisor = 'John Woor';
}
```

html file:

```
 <mat-slide-toggle
      (click)="displayValue(element)"
      [checked]="element.status"
    ></mat-slide-toggle>
```

Edit:
This worked for me

```
   this.records = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataSource.data));
```

Comment: Sorry, its unclear, can you please elaborate, what's the problem and what is expected behavior?

Comment: Of course! when i assign value to  dataSource.data[index].supervisor i don't want to change  array named 'records'. at this moment both are changing

Comment: What data type is `value.key`? Unless it's some custom class implementing both `toString` and `valueOf`, `data[value.key!]` and `data[index]` are identical and interchangeable. and you can write: `displayValue(value: TicketsList) { const item = this.dataSource.data[value.key!]; item.status = !item.status; item.supervisor = 'John Woor'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Please use loadash `cloneDeep` instead. It will create a deep copy and eliminate this problem!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.searchTickets().subscribe((resp) => {
  this.dataSource.data = resp.entities;
  this.records = cloneDeep(this.dataSource.data);
  })
```

Comment: I think OP wants more something like `this.records = cloneDeep(this.dataSource.data);` so that the two arrays contain similar and not the same items.

Comment: @domekker does this change fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `Object.assign`:

```
this.records = Object.assign([], this.dataSource.data);
```